# Executing priority of fetch() and setTimeout() in Chrome

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, fetch, settimeout

To my understanding of the event loop, the following code will output 'Sync 2' then 'Sync 4' first (synchronous code), then 'Promise 3' (fetch returns a Promise which would be placed in the microtask queue and will be executed after the synchronous code finishes and data comes back from the API), finally 'Async 1' (setTimeout would be placed in the macrotask/callback queue with the lowest priority).

However, in the lastest version Chrome, I always got 'Async 1' before 'Promise 3' if I set setTimeout() to 0 like below. Is there anything I misunderstand? Is it possible that a not-yet-resolved Promise gets lower priority than something in the macrotask queue here?

```
setTimeout(() => console.log('Async 1'), 0);

console.log('Sync 2')

fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/javascript-tutorial/en.javascript.info/commits').then(() => console.log('Promise 3'))

console.log('Sync 4')
```

Comment: the order depends on how long the fetch actually takes - settimeout of 0 wont wait for a fetch to complete - the microtask (promise) queue deals with Promises, not network requests

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `fetch` call has to at least go to browser cache and possibly to the network (to revalidate something in cache), so you can't make any assumptions at all about the timing of the call to your fulfillment handler on it other than that it won't be synchronous. The fulfillment handler call might be queued immediately (though I would tend to doubt it) in which case it would run before the next task (the `setTimeout` callback), but more likely it will be held up at least briefly. Fundamentally, this is down to the implementation of `fetch` in the browser, which is implementation-dependent, not about tasks or microtasks.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with 'a not-yet-resolved promise', even in the microtask queue, will have lower priority than others in the task queue? Or it's just the implementation of fetch that decides the order here, i.e. whether it's gonna queue the promise before or after setTimeout?

Comment: @JohnnyHuynh - A pending promise (a promise that isn't settled yet) isn't in the microtask queue at all. That doesn't happen until the promise is settled (fulfilled or rejected). It's the fulfillment/rejection callback that goes in the microtask queue. So you queue your task (`setTimeout`), start your `fetch`, and (apparently) the `fetch` doesn't settle the promise for X time. In the meantime, there's a turn of the event loop so your `setTimeout` callback is called. At some point, the `fetch` mechanism fulfills the promise, which queues a microtask, which gets run when microtasks are next run.

Answer (score 2):

> (fetch returns a Promise which would be placed in the microtask queue and will be executed after the synchronous code finishes and data comes back from the API)

This is only true if the Promise that is returned *resolves immediately* - for example, with `Promise.resolve`. If the Promise returned by `fetch` resolved immediately, you'd be right, and the `Promise 3` would log before the `setTimeout`'s.

But `fetch` does *not* resolve immediately - it requires the endpoint to respond first, and that takes *some time*, so you see the `setTimeout` log first.

Comment: so a not-yet-resolved promise will be queued in the microtask queue first but doesn't have priority over other things in the task queue until it resolves, or such promise won't even go to the queue if it's not already resolved?

Comment: A `.then` callback only goes into the microtask queue *when* the Promise resolves. Since the Promise hasn't resolved yet, it hasn't entered any queue; the `setTimeout` callback runs first. Then, some few millisecond later when the request completes, the `fetch` Promise resolves, and then it goes into the microtask queue.

Comment: @CertainPerformance - Just a nit: The term is "settles," not "resolves." Resolving a promise doesn't necessariy settle it (you can resolve it to another promise).

Answer (score 0):

Although `fetch` returns a promise as result, but `fetch` is actually a network request, a I/O operation belongs to macrotask.

---

A promised function or method does not means its all period is a microtask.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what's happening in your code:

1. A task is added to the Task Queue using `setTimeout`
2. `console.log('Sync 2')` is logged
3. `fetch` is called. However, `fetch` makes the network request asynchronously and returns immediately. When the request is completed and a response is received, its `.then` is added to the **Microtask Queue**.
4. `console.log('Sync 4')` is logged.
5. Once the main code completes, the engine checks if there are any tasks in the Microtask Queue. **At this point, the response from the fetch might not have arrived yet, so there's nothing in the Microtask Queue.**
6. There's a task in the Task Queue, which is added by `setTimeout`. Therefore, `"Async 1"` is logged.
7. Subsequently, the response for the `fetch` arrives, and the `.then` method added to the Microtask Queue is executed. `"Promise 3"` gets logged.

If you create a function like the one below for testing and call that just before calling `console.log('Sync 4')`, you'll see `"Promise 3"` will be logged before `"Async 1"`.

```js
function blockFor400ms() {
  let start = Date.now();
  let duration = 0;
  let count = 0;

  while (duration < 400) {
      count++;
      
      for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
          Math.sqrt(i);
      }

      duration = Date.now() - start;
  }

  console.log(`The loop took aprroximetaly ${duration} ms.`);
}
```

Hope this helps.